Milne-Thomson Circle Theorem for Multiple Circles in Potential Flow
I'm currently studying potential flow in fluid dynamics and have been utilizing the Milne-Thomson Circle Theorem to analyze the flow around a single circular cylinder. This theorem has been instrumental in obtaining the complex potential and ensuring that the boundary conditions on the circular obstacle are satisfied exactly.
However, I've encountered a challenge when dealing with multiple circular obstacles. I was wondering:
Is there a generalization of the Milne-Thomson Circle Theorem that can accommodate more than one circle?
Specifically, is there a method or an analytical approach to determine the complex potential for potential flow around multiple circles, ensuring that the boundary conditions on all the circles are simultaneously satisfied?

Yes but it is more complicated. Starting from an original complex potential $w$ with singularities outside the circles, the resulting complex potential $W$ from the inclusion of the obstacles will be:
$$
W = \sum_{g\in G_0}w(g(z))+\sum_{g\in G-G_0}\overline w(g(z))
$$
with $G$ the group of transformations generated by the inversions about each circles:
$$
g_i: z\to \frac{r_i^2}{\overline{z-c_i}}
$$
with $i$ the index of the circle, $r_i$ its radius and $c_i$ its center. $G_0$ is the subgroup of conformal maps of $G$ while $G-G_0$ is the subset of anti-conformal maps (each transformation is a composition of an even number of inversions and odd number of inversions respectively). Note that this is consistent with the case where you only have one circle.
In general, it is hard to compute the series explicitly, especially for an arbitrary initial $w$. With two circles, the group is simple enough so you can compute things analytically. This is just like for the classic electrostatics exercise of calculating the capacity of two spheres. As soon as you have more circles, things start to get very complicates as the group is typically free and the sum is typically hard to perform. However, numerically, you can get a pretty good picture by restricting to words up to a finite (not too large) length of inversions.

I wanted to thank you for your informative response. Your insights were very helpful and have piqued my interest in learning more about this.
Could you please provide any sources or articles that support the points you mentioned in your answer? Having access to additional references would greatly enhance my understanding of the topic.
I appreciate your time and assistance.
